# Rename node and delete relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to rename a node in a graph in neo4j without tempering the relationships of that node. Also how to delete a relationship between two nodes. please assist me with the cypher syntax.

Comment: What is for you `rename a node` ? What have tried so for ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find many tips in [the official documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/)

[How to delete relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/delete/#delete-delete-relationships-only)

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Andres' })-[r:KNOWS]->()
DELETE r
```

[How to add a new label](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/#set-set-a-label-on-a-node)

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Stefan' })
SET n:German
RETURN n.name, labels(n) AS labels
```

[How to remove a label](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/remove/#remove-remove-a-label-from-a-node)

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
REMOVE n:German
RETURN n.name, labels(n)
```